# Changing the Garbage Collector on your JVM

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

My *understanding* is that the JVM specification only defines the *behavior* of a garbage collector, but does not provide implementation details. This means it is up to the JVM implementation to build the garbage collector out.

There appears to be 3rd party garbage collectors such as the [Azul Pauseless GC](http://www.azulsystems.com/zing/pgc). To me, this implies that my JVM implementation, say HotSpot or JRockit, is configured by default to use its own built-in garbage collector. **But**, perhaps through configuration, I could use a 3rd party garbage collector (such as the one by Azul, or another).

So I ask: How does one "swap out" the built-in garbage collector with another one? If the answer is JVM implementation-specific, let's assume HotSpot.

Comment: That's not a garbage collector that you linked to; it's an *entire JVM* having its own custom collector.  It doesn't have to be configurable at all, if you're changing out the whole JVM.

Comment: This question is a specific tooling implementation question (rather than conceptual design and architecture) and should instead be asked on Stack Overflow (the answer, if there is one, is some application of [command line switches](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html#available_collectors)).

Comment: Also explained here: http://javapapers.com/java/types-of-java-garbage-collectors/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Garbage collectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) and code generators (in particular the [JIT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) engine inside any industrial [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine)) are tightly related, in particular because most GCs are generational, and need some write barrier (which is a constraint on the code generator), and also depend upon multithreading issues. And the GC is also (obviously) tied to object allocations which is JVM specific. Read the [GC handbook](http://gchandbook.org/) for more explanations.

Generational GCs are handling differently young objects (which *usually* die quickly) from older ones. They often copy the live young objects in some older memory region, then the entire birth region can be released. But they need to track any *old* object which has been modified to hold a pointer to the newest region. This is a *write barrier* and needs special code to be emitted by the JIT engine for field modifications of (young) object.

<sup>BTW, the [Azul PGC](http://www.azulsystems.com/zing/pgc) link *you* gave has a video explaining all that!</sup>

So in practice you cannot easily plug another GC inside your JVM without patching *significantly* the JVM code.

Comment: Thanks @Basile (+1) - I understand everything you said except this bit: "*GCs are generational, and need some write barrier (which is a constraint on the code generator)*". Any chance you can elaborate more on what this means? What write barrier, and why is this write barrier a "constraint" on the code generator? Thanks again!

Comment: @smeeb: I tried to explain a little bit, but I don't have the patience to explain what a good book of several hundred pages would teach you.